# linux extract string between tags and paste between others tags

Tags: linux, sed

I have files with xml text like:

```
<tag1>unknown string1</tag1>blablabla....<tag2></tag2>
```

I want use sed (or another command) to extract string between tag's 1 and paste between tag's 2, to result:

```
<tag1>unknown string1</tag1>blablabla....<tag2>unknown string1</tag2>
```

Thanks.

I found a solution!.

```
sed 's/\(.*<tag1>\)\(.*\)\(<\/tag1>.*<tag2>\)\(**\)\(<\/tag2>.*\)/\1\2\3\2\5/' file
```

Divide entire file in references, and after reorder this in convenience.

Comment: Thanks Kalanidhi and Potong for yours answers, but they do not work.  I edit the question for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sed command

**Command :**

```
sed 'N;s/\(<tag1>\(.*\)<\/tag1>\n<tag2>\).*\(<\/tag2>\)/\1\2\3/' FIleName
```

**Output:**

```
<tag1>unknown string1</tag1>
<tag2>unknown string1</tag2>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/<tag1>/h;/<tag2>/{G;s/>.*(<.*)\n.*>(.*)<.*/>\2\1/}' file
```

This makes a copy of `tag1` in the hold space (HS) and on encountering `tag2` appends the HS to the current line and uses pattern matching to produce the required string.

N.B. this assumes one tag per line.